# Why isn't my Unity-built Android app generating a CSV file when it works in the editor?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, export-to-csv

I am trying to build an application in Unity for an android device. In this, some Datas are being fetched and some are user entered and are being stored in **Dictionary<>** in the format of **Dictionary<string, string> chairDataStored = new Dictionary<string, string>**, where **chairDataStored** is the variable in which all the Datas are stored.

Next, on button click these Datas will be converted and saved into CSV file.
Code for these is present below.

```
    string filename = "";
    string CSVFileName = "AllChairData.csv";
    string value_name;
    string value_id;
    string value_coor_x;
    string value_coor_y;
    string value_coor_z;
    string value_color;
    string value_height;
    string value_width;    



    void Start()
    {
        filename = Application.dataPath + CSVFileName;
        filename = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath + CSVFileName);
    }


    public void OnCickCSVFileSave()
    {
        Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> DataList = chairDataStored;


        if (DataList.Count > 0)
        {
            TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(filename, false);
            tw.WriteLine("Name,ID,Coordinate - X,Coordinate - Y,Coordinate - Z,Color,Height,Width");
            tw.Close();

            tw = new StreamWriter(filename, true);
            foreach(var outer in DataList)
            {
                foreach(var inner in outer.Value)
                {
                    if (inner.Key == "ID")
                        value_id = inner.Value;
                    else if (inner.Key == "Coordinate - X")
                        value_coor_x = inner.Value;
                    else if (inner.Key == "Coordinate - Y")
                        value_coor_y = inner.Value;
                    else if (inner.Key == "Coordinate - Z")
                        value_coor_z = inner.Value;
                    else if (inner.Key == "Color")
                        value_color = inner.Value;
                    else if (inner.Key == "Height")
                        value_height = inner.Value;
                    else if (inner.Key == "Width")
                        value_width = inner.Value;
                }
                tw.WriteLine(outer.Key + "," + value_id + "," + value_coor_x + "," + value_coor_y + "," + value_coor_z + "," + value_color + "," + value_height + "," + value_width);
                Debug.Log("CSV");
            }
            tw.Close();
        }
    }
```

Now, the issue is when I run this code in Unity Editor, the CSV File gets generated successfully with proper format and as per requirement. But when I build it for android as an .apk file, the application takes the data but on button click csv file is not built.

I have also wrote the user permission for storage access.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.unity3d.player"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
  <!-- Request File System Access Permissions -->
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  
    <application>
        <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity"
                  android:theme="@style/UnityThemeSelector">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true" />
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

I have tried to built it with .txt format file to see, if any file is getting generated or not but in that scenario, TXT file is created but no data is showing in that.

I have been looking for any reference or video for this, but the one I found are all for Unity Editor or Android Studio.

[Used this Youtube video for reference for exporting Unity Data to CSV File](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sU_Y2g1Nidk)

I have searched in here too but failed to find answer.
It would be helpful, if there is any changes that I have to do or any error that I have missed that you can point it out.

Comment: What is the actual (full) path where you are saving those? Does your application have permisson to write inside folder right next to the game executables? What would be the appropriate path?

Comment: Have you checked for the errors? If not Check in the Android Studio or Unity's [Logcat Package](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.mobile.android-logcat@0.1/manual/index.html#installing-android-logcat)

Comment: @Tatranskymedved The actual path is Internal storage\Android\data\com.PD.UI\files\AllChairData.csv and yes my file has the permission.

Comment: @GhostThePunisher, there is no error mentioned in the Logcat

Comment: Good, we are making progress. what kind of error that is?

Comment: @GhostThePunisher There is a new error that got rose after I added "Internet Permission"  in the Manifest File. But the error is only in one device. The CSV file is created but it is showing the file is empty. I have raised a question regarding that too.

Comment: Can you please tell us the error that you are getting?

Comment: @GhostThePunisher Error 0x800710D2: The library, drive, or media pool is empty.

Comment: @PD After reading the error I've posted an answer for you, that should help.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, even though many things are working the same, Unity Editor is not the same as the build.

You just found one of these differences. According to the documentation of [`Application.dataPath`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-dataPath.html), on Android platform it refers to the apk or oob file.

If you want to save something, you should use [`Application.persistentDataPath`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-persistentDataPath.html) instead.

Comment: I have used Application.persistentDataPath but no file is getting created.

Comment: Where are you looking for the file? How do you know that there is no file? What do you see in the logcat?

Comment: The file is getting stored in package folder of the project in android folder of android device.

Answer (score 0):

From your code and the error you are getting, my best guess is that you need to create a file first using `System.IO.FileStream`. And you should use that `FileStream`'s object to initialize the `StreamWriter`. After implementing this your code should look like as follows.

```
        var fileName = "<your File Name including the Path>";
        FileStream fs = null;
        TextWriter tw = null;
        try
        {
            fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create);
            tw = new StreamWriter(fs);
            tw.WriteLine("Name,ID,Coordinate - X,Coordinate - Y,Coordinate - Z,Color,Height,Width");
            tw.Close();

            tw = new StreamWriter(fs);
            //Your code to write whatever you want in the file...
            tw.Close();
        }
        finally
        {
            //close the text writer
            tw?.Close();

            //close the file stream
            fs?.Close();
            fs?.Dispose();
        }
```

For more reference please refer to [StreamWriter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter.-ctor?view=net-7.0) and [FileMode Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filemode?view=net-7.0)

**Note:** `?.` operator will only call the methods if the given object is not null. in other words, this is equivalent to the following snippet.

```
if (fs != null)
{
    fs.Close();
    fs.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response.
I have tried the code you have give but I am getting error for this for the line
                     tw = new StreamWriter(fs);
The error is 
"ArgumentException: Stream was not writable."

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, @PD just wants to check what line to be exact, because there are two similar lines in the code. First one or the second one? If it is happening in the second line I would suggest not closing the stream the first time. And continue with the stream which is created right after creating the file stream.

Comment: It might be happening because of the multiple writer instance from a single file stream.

Comment: The issue is occurring with only few android devices only.

Comment: Did you notice any similarities in those devices, like a similar OS version, or 
a same manufacturer or something like that?

Comment: No,that's why it was little weird. For example, one of the device is Samsung M31 and another is Samsung M31s but the OS and version both were same.

Comment: Check if the devices getting this error, are running Android 13 or

Comment: I have set the lowest API level as 26, so the minimum version is taking Android 8. I don't think version is the issue. Though I have checked, there was no such error.

Comment: Can you share error with me? I might get some idea as to why this is happening? One more thing I would suggest you to make an Il2Cpp build and check again in all the devices. and let me know the outcum.

Comment: I can share the link of the error as I have issued this in different post.  
 "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76431014/csv-file-generated-from-unity-build-android-app-but-showing-error-when-tried-to".   And I have built it with IL2CPP.

Comment: ```ArgumentException: Stream was not writable.``` So you are not getting this error anymore. right?

Comment: Please use a ```try-catch ``` for the code, and do not create two different ```StreamWriter``` for a single file. See if you can find any error in the ```catch(Exception e){ }```. You should only close the ```StreamWriter``` in ```finally{ }```